# MySQL Conditional INSERT

Tags: mysql, insert-select

I want to do a conditional insert with MySQL. I have 2 tables (Car and CarType).

The Car table got a coloumn called `typeId`, which points to an entry in the CarType table.

I only want to insert a row in the Car table if the given typeId exists in the CarType table.

I've tried some Googling, and tried a couple of solutions. Here is what I found
(but it does not work):

```
INSERT INTO Car (title, licensePlate, carType 
SELECT 'Ford Transit', 'SV 32 654', '13' 
FROM DUAL 
    WHERE EXISTS (SELECT typeId FROM CarType WHERE typeId = 13)
```

Comment: dup : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/913841/mysql-conditional-insert

Comment: I've seen that and tried that (as you would have known if you actually saw my code). It doesn't work. Not for me atleast.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you misleading by the example, it can be as simple as this :

```
INSERT INTO Car (title, licensePlate, carType) 
  SELECT 'Ford Transit', 'SV 32 654', '13' 
  FROM CarType WHERE typeId=13;
```