# MYSQL Next Previous Record

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to be able to find the next and previous record going from a non auto incremental id.

The correct sort order from the database uses this order by statement:

The below works only to list all results from a search. 
ORDER BY length(general.blockid), general.blockid, length(general.plotid), general.plotid

The page that needs to know the next and previous record, holds the unique id/varchar in the URL as simply ?id=100_1A

In the url variable example above,

100_1A is in the db as blockplot

100 is the in the db as blockid

1A is in the datbase as plotid

When I am on the record 100_1A the next record should be 100_1B.
The previous record to 100_1a should be 99_6C

My problem is that how do i query the database for the next record when I dont know the order until it is sorted?

The sort order I typed is a working sort for the search results page.

When a user clicks to go into a specific record, the id is passed to the ur on the detail-view.php?id=100_1a

From the view page i need to take 100_1A and use the same sort to see what record is after and before 100_1A

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this

```
set @row:=0;
select * from 
(
  select *, (@row:=@row+1) as row_number from your_tables
  order by 
    length(general.blockid), general.blockid, 
    length(general.plotid), general.plotid
) as rowset 
WHERE id='100_A';
```

the above will give you the position of 100_A with the refer to the column `row_number`, and you can use that column to determine the next/prev row like,

```
set @row:=0;
select * from 
(
  select *, (@row:=@row+1) as row_number from your_tables
  order by 
    length(general.blockid), general.blockid, 
    length(general.plotid), general.plotid
) as rowset 
where 
  row_number in(first_query_row+1, first_query_row-1);
```

Please note that the query cost might very expensive if table is big,
and you can consider to create a <strike>view</strike> summary table to store the row_number and uniqid

Example of creating summary table

```
create table ordering_table
(
  row_number int(10) unsigned not null default 0,
  blockid varchar(255),
); /* no index, define yourself later */

 set @row:=0
 insert into ordering_table
   select @row:=@row+1, blockid from your_tables
   order by ...
```

Comment: the table is huge around 14,000 records. and what I am working on now, i would just like the next record after and the one previous. I will give you explanation some time and see if i can get it to work.

Comment: When you say create a view to store the row_number what do you mean?

Comment: Wiew has some restrictions such as does not allow variable in select query. Proper replacement will be create a summary table that contains row number + the non-integer ID

Comment: When you say proper replacement. Do you mean create a view with a row number and non-integer id?

Comment: Yes, **BUT** creating view does not allow variables, so use a summary table instead.

Comment: Is a summary table just a temp table with data?

Comment: Yes, but whether is a temporary table or not, if up to you to define

Comment: If i need to create a new question I will.

Lets say I want to create this table. How can i take my existing table, sort it like i need it and then take a value from it and create an integer row key

Comment: I posted some example, you can take a look, there are couple of ways to achieve this, so, this is just one of the possible ways

Comment: thanks for your time.

was this it? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4358730/mysql-conditional-insert/4359156#4359156

Comment: What a great day to learn a new trick. I created a key index table to do what i need and i can run this after an insert transaction of this table and re-create the index as needed.

Insert INTO test3 (blockplotid)
Select blockplotid from general
ORDER BY length(general.blockid), general.blockid, length(general.plotid), general.plotid