# If row dont exist, insert instead of update

Tags: mysql

```
UPDATE userpostratings SET rating = $rating WHERE postID = 8
```

If a there isnt a row in userpostratings with postID = 8 i wanna INSERT instead. Could this be done with sql or should I do it in php

Thanks

Tomek

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/913841/mysql-conditional-insert

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I update if exists, insert if not (aka upsert or merge) in MySQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1218905/how-do-i-update-if-exists-insert-if-not-aka-upsert-or-merge-in-mysql)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a UNIQUE index on postID, then you can do something like:

```
INSERT INTO userpostratings (rating, postID) VALUES ($rating, 8)
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE rating = $rating;
```

Comment: True, it requires a unique index. That's why I wrote "If you have a UNIQUE index...". Can I assume that this was your revenge downvote?

Answer (score 4):

see here: [How do I update if exists, insert if not (AKA "upsert" or "merge") in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1218905/759701)

Answer (score -1):

here you go

http://nl2.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-affected-rows.php

```
> mysql_query("UPDATE mytable SET used=1
> WHERE id < 10"); printf ("Updated
> records: %d\n",
> mysql_affected_rows());
```

Comment: This doesn't do anything like OP was asking about.

Comment: ow..is that so?  if mysql_affected_rows()==0 then insert

Comment: You didn't explain that. Plus, this requires two statements where one will do.