# mysql query to delete records that match multiple fields

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, database-design

I have a database that looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE cargo (
    cargodate int unsigned NOT NULL,
    cargoname CHAR(128) NOT NULL,
    lattitude double NOT NULL,
    longitude double NOT NULL,
    user CHAR(64) NOT NULL
) type=MyISAM;
```

I want to make sure there are no more than 5 entries for this cargo at the same location with the same user.  A user can have multiple entries as long as they are in different locations (lattitude, longitude).

How do I make my sql INSERT statement take care of this?

Right now I execute:

```
   INSERT INTO cargo VALUES (UNIX_TIMESTAMP(), '{$cargoname}', '{$lat}', '{$lng}', '{$user}');
```

I can do a DELETE FROM, but I want to only delete entries if there are more than 5.  In that case I want to delete the oldest entries

Thanks
Deshawnt

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/913841/mysql-conditional-insert

Comment: @ShinTakezou: He wants to invalidate the oldest row, not prohibit the new one.

Comment: @Wrikken hm sorry; instead of invalidating, he could do an update over the record he would "invalidate", e.g. like `update ... set column = newvalue .... where condition of an invalid record`... though this way if the record does not exist, it would fail (and if they exist more records, he would update all); then maybe something like "update ... if exists, otherwise insert" query?

Comment: Is InnoDB available to you? i.e., transactions.

Comment: Ermmmm, for identifying the oldest 5 entries (in case of more than 5 entries) there has to be a counter (per cargo/location/user) or a timestamp column

Answer (score 1):

You could use triggers http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/triggers.html
Just after insert you may delete all not needed entries.

Answer (score 0):

Using a trigger as mentioned by Ruslan Polutsygan would be the most natural solution.

If you don't want to mess around with them, then the alternative would be to run:

```
SELECT * FROM cargo ORDER BY cargodate DESC LIMIT 4,18446744073709551615
```

before you run an insert, and then delete the rows that are returned by that query, and then do the insert.

As a side-note, the number 18446744073709551615 was taken out of the example from the [MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html):

> To retrieve all rows from a certain offset up to the end of the result set, you can use some large number for the second parameter