# INSERT query with if exist statement

Tags: mysql

I have two tables:

1. `purchase_mis(id, user_id, total_purchased, date)`
2. `daily_purchase(id, user_id, product_id, paid_amount, purchase_date)`

I have a CRON file that runs every night, it counts the daily purchase from the "daily_purchase" table and runs insert into "purchase_mis".

For example:

```
SELECT
    COUNT(*) AS purchase_count,
    purchase_date
FROM daily_purchase
GROUP BY user_id;
```

This returns the purchase_count for every user and then it will be inserted to the "purchase_mis" table.

```
INSERT INTO
    purchase_mis(user_id, total_purchased, date)
VALUES
    ('2', 'purchase_count', 'purchase_date');
```

But before inserting, it needs to check if the purchased information of user_id = 2 for some date "purchase_date" has already been inserted so it should not be inserted again.

I want something like the below query:

```
INSERT INTO
    purchase_mis(user_id, total_purchased, date)
VALUES
    ('2', 'purchase_count', 'purchase_date')
WHERE date NOT EXISTS (SELECT date FROM purchase_mis WHERE user_id = '2');
```

Comment: This is looks like a dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/913841/mysql-conditional-insert

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO
    purchase_mis(user_id, total_purchased, date)
VALUES
    ('2', 'purchase_count', 'purchase_date');
```

Comment: Why should OP try this? Can you discuss why and maybe add more detail as to why this is the answer?

Answer (score 0):

You could use an [`INSERT IGNORE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert.html) statement. To do so, you have to have a unique key over `user_id` and `date`. Then the following query, will insert only those values, for which the key is not present (meaning users which had no entry for that date) and issue a warning for others, which you could ignore here.

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO
    purchase_mis(user_id, total_purchased, date)
( SELECT
    user_id,
    COUNT(*),
    purchase_date
FROM daily_purchase
GROUP BY user_id );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this.

```
INSERT INTO purchase_mis(user_id, total_purchased, date)
SELECT user_id, purchase_date, count(*)
FROM daily_purchase a
LEFT OUTER JOIN purchase_mis b
ON a.user_id = b.user_id
AND a.purchase_date = b.date
WHERE b.user_id IS NULL
GROUP BY user_id, purchase_date
```