# INSERT if related row does not exist

Tags: mysql, sql, insert

`INSERT IGNORE` doesn't work because there won't actually be a key conflict.

This is for a progress queue.  For one application I don't want two rows with status `S` (for "started").  However other applications should be able to - in particular if I want to force two work items to happen at once, I can. So that's why it's not a database constraint.

So it's a little tricky to say in SQL "insert where does not exist."  This works:

```
insert into user_queue_google
(user_id, status, start_timestamp)
(select 221, 'S', NOW() FROM filter_type
WHERE 221 not in (select user_id from user_queue_google where status = 'S') limit 1);
```

The problem is `filter_type` is a completely unrelated table that I just know is small and happens to never be empty. If it were empty for some reason, this would fail.

Can I avoid this very horrible hack without resorting to stored programs or IF/THEN logic in my SQL program?

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL Conditional Insert](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/913841/mysql-conditional-insert)

Answer (score 0):

use the `dual` system dummy table

```
insert into user_queue_google (user_id, status, start_timestamp)
select 221, 'S', NOW()
from dual
WHERE not exists 
(
   select user_id 
   from user_queue_google 
   where status = 'S' 
   and user_id = 221
)
```

> You are permitted to specify DUAL as a dummy table name in situations where no tables are referenced

[Source](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html)

Comment: What about this bit in the doc - " MySQL may ignore the clauses." How bad is that?

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a `UNIQUE` index for `INSERT IGNORE` to work effectively. What you could do is add an additional column that defaults to something harmless but could be changed to unique the key:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX index_block ON user_queue_google (user_id, force);
```

Set `force` as a column that has `DEFAULT 0`. If you want to force two jobs to run at the same time, set it to something else to avoid a conflict:

```
UPDATE user_queue_google SET status='S', force=UNIX_TIMESTAMP() WHERE user_id=221
```

That'll free up a new slot for inserting new jobs.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
insert into user_queue_google
(user_id, status, start_timestamp)
select
    A.user_id,
    A.status,
    A.start_timestamp
FROM
  (SELECT
     221 user_id, 
     'S' status, 
     NOW() start_timestamp) AS A
  LEFT JOIN user_queue_google ON A.user_id = user_queue_google.user_id AND A.status = user_queue_google.status
WHERE
   user_queue_google.user_id IS NULL;
```

See attached fiddle [Insert if row doesn't exist](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ccaa3/1)