# Ignore insert if exist in table in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 6 columns in my table:

```
Id  | Name | Mail id | Gender | Contact Number | father name
```

while inserting a data into table i wanted to check condition like if `Name,mailid,contact number` already exists then insert should not happen else record should be inserted.

Can any one suggest how to check the condition while inserting a record.

Comment: Maybe this help you:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/913841/mysql-conditional-insert

Comment: If the tuple `Name, MailID, ContactNumber` should be unique, you should define a unique index on it to enforce that constraint.  Then you can use `INSERT IGNORE` which is simpler.  Otherwise go with Muhammed Ali's answer.

Comment: refer the link below it works pretty well
http://stackoverflow.com/a/3164741/3209804

Answer (score 2):

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Table_Name WHERE Condition you are checking)
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO .............   ---<----- Your Insert Statement.....

END
```

Comment: It should be `IF NOT EXISTS ...`

Comment: Cheers this what happens when you'er watching tele and answering a question :)

Answer (score 0):

You can define an index on multiple columns, e.g.:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX arbitrary_index_name ON table_name (Name, mailid, contactnumber);
```

Answer (score 0):

I also faced similar situation, you can do this by adding unique constraint to your table and using 'insert ignore' statement to add data.

Create table statement:

```
CREATE TABLE Student (
Id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
NAME VARCHAR(50),
Mailid VARCHAR(50),
Gender CHAR,
contactnumber BIGINT,
fathername VARCHAR(50),
UNIQUE(NAME,Mailid,contactnumber));
```

Insert Ignore statement:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO student(NAME, Mailid,Gender,contactnumber,fathername) VALUES('Shekhar', 's@s.com', 'M', 987654321, 'Joshi');
```