# How to insert in mysql if record does not exist?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

my db is

**TABLE**

```
        id | new_id  |  affiliate_id  | s_percent | a_percent |   date  
        ---+---------+----------------+-----------+-----------+--------------
        32 |  970    |     34         |     0.25  |   0.2     | 1404387120
        33 |  972    |     29         |     0.25  |   0.2     | 1404482095
        34 |  973    |     26         |     0.25  |   0.33    | 1405752775
```

and i want to insert new record here .If `new_id` already exists in its column then it do not insert

Comment: concept you'll need: `primary_key` it is not `db` it is your `table structure`. and please have a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/913841/mysql-conditional-insert

Comment: yes this is my table.. well what should i do in this case?

Comment: if i understand correctly, you need unique key for `new_id` column, to ensure, there is unique value in `new_id`... therefore, insert will not insert the row, if the `new_id` value is already in the table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not a good approach, however if you insist to do so, you can use below code:

```
INSERT INTO table_listnames (id,new_id,affiliate_id,s_percent,a_percent,date )
SELECT * FROM (SELECT 34,973,26,0.25,0.33,1405752775) AS tmp
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT new_id FROM table_listnames WHERE new_id = '970'
) LIMIT 1;
```

It would be better to create a `UNIQUE INDEX` on the field which should be unique (new_id), then use either:

```
normal INSERT (and handle the error if the new_id already exists),
INSERT IGNORE (which will fail silently cause a warning (instead of error) if new_id already exists)
INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
```