# Error with SQL query with WHERE NOT EXISTS

Tags: mysql, sql

### My aim

I'm trying to perform the following sql query:

```
INSERT INTO api(site,key) VALUES ('example.com','a-random-key') WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM api WHERE site='example.com');
```

In order to insert a new row with a site and a corresponding key if there isn't already one with that site (eg insert 'example.com' with the associated key 'a-random-key' if there isn't an other record with the site 'example.com').

### What isn't working

I'm getting the following error:

> `#`1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
> near 'WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM api WHERE site='example.com')'
> at line 1

### What I've tried

I've tried to perform the two queries separatedly, and they both work.

### My question

How can I make the query work?

Comment: Where clause cannot be used in insert query also for your problem add unique index on site column

Comment: [I'd read that it's possible](http://stackoverflow.com/a/913929/4086503), I hadn't noticed about the first "select". Thanks for your suggestion: following it, will I be able to check if the record was actually inserted or not using PHP's mysqli_num_rows()?

Comment: See the linked answer again where clause is used for select statement not for insert

Comment: Yeah I've just noticed about that, you're right, thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want to try something like this:

```
INSERT INTO api (site, `key`)
SELECT 'example.com','a-random-key'
  FROM dual
 WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM api WHERE site='example.com');
```

I don't think `WHERE NOT EXISTS` can be used in an `INSERT` query without a select. Please see [SQL Fiddle demo here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0c340f/1). Also, the above `SELECT` statement doesn't work if you don't use `FROM dual`.

**UPDATE** A second issue is that the column `key` should be surrounded by backticks ... I think MySQL is choking on it because it is a reserved word.

Comment: Yes, see the SQL Fiddle demo to which I linked. I believe it was added in MySQL 5.0.

Comment: @David Faber: I don't see `FROM DUAL` in your example, but yes, it works. That's funny, thanks.

Comment: @zerkms, it is on the right hand side, after the table creation. At least, I see it!

Comment: Personally, I found it odd that `FROM dual` works but the query doesn't work if it is omitted.

Comment: @DavidFaber In the given link it's `    SELECT * FROM api` :-) You probably modified it but didn't provide the new link

Comment: I'm sorry, I meant left-hand side. It's part of the schema build.

Answer (score 3):

As people are suggesting, the better approach would be to add a unique index on site column (that way it wouldn't be inserted if site exists). Anyway, if that's not an option, I'd try this query:

```
INSERT INTO api(site, `key`)
SELECT * FROM (SELECT 'example.com','a-random-key') AS tmp
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM api WHERE site='example.com') LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: Thanks, that works! If I add a unique index, will I be able to check if the record was actually inserted or not using PHP's mysqli_num_rows() or will I have to use something else?

Comment: @Stubborn, if you add a unique index then the record won't be inserted - you'll probably want to trap the error raised.

Comment: My apologies, it works, but in SQL Fiddle at least `key` has to be surrounded by backticks

Comment: @DavidFaber Thanks :) I'm going to update the answer with the backticks