# INSERT WHERE NOT EXIST

Tags: mysql

**I tried following query :**

```
  INSERT INTO `chat_lines` (`channel`, `nick`, `value`)
    VALUES ('Alfa', 'Beta', '0')
    WHERE NOT EXIST
    (
    SELECT * 
    FROM `chat_lines` 
    WHERE `channel` = 'Alfa' AND `nick` = 'Beta'
    );
```

**How can I insert only if record doesn't exist yet?**

Channel and nick can't be unique, 
because one channel can have records with many nicks
and one nick can have many channels.

Something like:

```
(Alfa | Alfa)
(Alfa | Beta)
(Beta | Alfa)
(Beta | Beta).
```

So, I don't want to have two identical records like

```
(Alfa|Beta)(Alfa|Beta).
```

Or maybe there is other way to solve my problem?
I just want to create record with specific nick and channel 
if it doesn't exist, and if it exist, 
I want to incrase value.

@edit
I tried to use `REPLACE`. It works. But... I want to change `value = value + 1`. And it is only possible in `UPDATE` AFAIK. What can I do?

Comment: Appears to be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/913841/mysql-conditional-insert

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to 'insert if not exists' in MySQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1361340/how-to-insert-if-not-exists-in-mysql)

Comment: Why can you not add an unique key over channel and nick? `ALTER TABLE chat_lines ADD UNIQUE( channel , nick);`

Comment: @cSteusloff Will I be able to create two records where nick = Alfa if nick will be UNIQUE?
...

Comment: `UNIQUE( channel , nick)` creates a unique key on the *combination* of these 2 columns, not on *each* of them. Which means you can still have duplicates in `channel`, duplicates in `nick` but no duplicates on the combination of both, which is exactly what you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want only one `value` for each pair `(nick, channel)`, first create a unique index on this pair:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX `chat_lines_by_nick_channel`
ON `chat_lines` (`nick`, `channel`);
```

This lets you have rows with values `('Staisy', 'nesdev')`, `('Milo', 'nesdev')`, and `('Milo', 'fireworks')` for these fields, just not two separate rows with `('Milo', 'fireworks')`.

Then you can use `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` to have MySQL change `value` instead of inserting a new row, or `INSERT IGNORE INTO chat_lines` to leave it unchanged when you try to insert a new row. If you want to add 1 to `value`, for instance, you can do this:

```
INSERT INTO chat_lines (`nick`, `channel`, `lines`)
VALUES ('Chester', 'orchard', 1)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `value` = `value` + 1
```

This will add a new row if there is no row matching `('Chester', 'orchard')`. Otherwise, it'll add 1 to the `value` in the existing row.

See also:

- [CREATE INDEX Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-index.html) in MySQL manual
- [INSERT IGNORE vs. ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/548541/insert-ignore-vs-insert-on-duplicate-key-update)

Comment: Thanks! I read about `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`, but couldn't make it works.

Answer (score 1):

Simply do

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO `chat_lines` (`channel`, `nick`, `value`)
    VALUES ('Alfa', 'Beta', '0');
```

See also `INSERT...ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE...` (not relevant, but similar).