# insert data to the DB only if it's not already exist

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I would like to insert data to the DB only if it's not already exist. so I'm using INSERT IGNORE.

The problem is with field "createDate" - it's change every second and that's turn the new data to be new/unique.
Is there any way to set the comparison fields for the SQL ?

```
$res = mysql_query ("INSERT IGNORE INTO `alerts` (userID, type, refID, title, openBy, createDate) VALUES (".$mainIndex['userID'].", 'comment',  ".$mainIndex['id'].", '".$contactName."', ".$mainIndex['userID'].", ".$todayLX.")");
```

Comment: Is createDate marked as a UNIQUE field in your database?

Comment: no...@Naruto..................................

Comment: so try insert without date and then update if record inserted, or check before insert if data exists

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/913841/mysql-conditional-insert

Comment: Define "exists", then put a unique key on it.

Comment: insert ignore works only when one of the inserting field is unique.