# Speeding up sql inserts on postgresql with JDBC?

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc

I have two methods below for checking if a match is in the database and if not if would call the insert method. My program has to go through thousands of rows and it takes a very long time. Am I doing this incorrectly? Anything I can do to significantly make this faster?

```
public Boolean isMatchIdInDatabase(String matchId) throws SQLException
{
    Connection conn = null;
    PreparedStatement pst = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    Boolean exists = false;

    try
    {
        Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, props);
        pst = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM match where match_id = ?");
        pst.setString(1, matchId);

        rs = pst.executeQuery();
        while (rs.next())
        {
            exists = rs.getBoolean(1);
        }

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally
    {
        pst.close();
        rs.close();
        conn.close();
    }

    return exists;
}

public Boolean insertMatchId(String matchId, String name, Timestamp birthdate, String bio, String accountId) throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException
{
    Connection conn = null;
    PreparedStatement pst = null;
    Boolean exists = false;

    try
    {
        Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, props);
        pst = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO match (match_id, name, birthdate, bio, account_id) values(?, ? , ?, ?, ?)");
        pst.setString(1, matchId);
        pst.setString(2, name);
        pst.setTimestamp(3, birthdate);
        pst.setString(4, bio);
        pst.setString(5, accountId);

        pst.executeUpdate();

    }
    finally
    {
        pst.close();
        conn.close();
    }

    return exists;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you calling first `isMatchIdInDatabase` then `insertMatchId` for many records?
Possible duplicate: [Efficient way to do batch INSERTS with JDBC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3784197/efficient-way-to-do-batch-inserts-with-jdbc)

It is an expensive operation to open a connection and query for a single record. If you do that thousands of times, it gets very slow. You should try to restructure your query so that you only use one `SELECT`. Then you can collect the records which you have to insert and doing it with batch insert.

Comment: I think the link you gave me should do it

Comment: added details on connections

Answer (score 0):

You could try changing your SQL query that inserts the row to insert only if the row isn't in the database by using `WHERE NOT EXISTS`.
This post seems to be relevant - I know it's for MySQL instead of PostgreSQL but the principles should be the same.
[MySQL Conditional Insert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/913841/mysql-conditional-insert)