# Why can't I use WHERE NOT EXISTS with INSERT?

Tags: postgresql

I want to insert a tag named "foo", unless it already exists. So I constructed the following query:

```
INSERT INTO "tag" ("name") VALUES ('foo') 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM "tag" WHERE ("tag"."name" = 'foo'));
```

But this will fail with the following error:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "WHERE"
LINE 1: INSERT INTO "tag" ("name") VALUES ('foo') WHERE NOT EXISTS (...
                                                  ^
```

I don't understand where the problem with that query is. Especially, since I can provide a subquery instead of `VALUES` and suddenly the query is perfectly fine:

```
INSERT INTO "tag" ("name") SELECT 'foo' AS name 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM "tag" WHERE ("tag"."name" = 'foo'));
```

This results in:

```
Query returned successfully: 0 rows affected, 11 ms execution time.
```

It's 0 rows, because the tag already exists.

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL Conditional Insert](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/913841/mysql-conditional-insert)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: MySQL behaves differently with regard to concurrency issues.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can, you just need to use the `INSERT INTO ... SELECT ...` form.

```
INSERT INTO "tag" ("name")
SELECT 'foo'
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM "tag" WHERE ("tag"."name" = 'foo'));
```

However, it doesn't do what you want. At least not under concurrent workloads. You can still get unique violations or duplicate inserts.

See:

- [How to UPSERT (MERGE, INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE UPDATE) in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17267417/398670)
- [Insert, on duplicate update in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1109061/398670)

Comment: Why is the syntax with `VALUES` not valid, but the one involving the subquery is?

Comment: @OliverSalzburg `VALUES` doesn't have a `WHERE` clause. It's a simple list of one or more tuples. The syntax doesn't allow for anything else. So, basically, it's not valid because it's specified not to be valid. See http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-values.html

Comment: Ah! I didn't realize that the `WHERE` belongs to `VALUES`. Thanks for the help :)

Comment: @OliverSalzburg: no. The `where` does **not** belong to `values` it belongs to the `SELECT`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: What I was trying to say is, when PostgreSQL reports the error, it indicates to me, that `WHERE` is not a valid keyword in the given context. I assumed that the context is the complete `SELECT` statement, when PostgreSQL is trying to tell me that the context is the `VALUES` part of the statement. I hope that explanation is clear enough. Rest assured that I have understood the problem well enough now ;)

Comment: "it doesn't do what you want. At least not under concurrent workloads" do you happen to have a reference for that please?

Comment: @RedYeti The PostgreSQL manual. Read the chapters on MVCC, locking and concurrency. In short nothing stops two concurrent txns evaluating the subquery, neither finding a row, then both inserting a new row. Read the documentation on INSERT ... ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING for the correct way