# Preventing MySQL duplicates by comparing fractional seconds

Tags: mysql, sql, timestamp

I've spent over a week trying to see how to prevent duplicate mysql entries into my table. How can I prevent this from happening? I don't want a user to update his/her location if I have an entry from the last 5 seconds, down to the fractional seconds. For instance, I just want the very first entry, and a way to ignore the subsequent entries.

The type of my column is timestamp(6)

```
|         40 |       4 |           5 | 2016-03-05 22:19:57.572771 |
|         41 |       4 |           5 | 2016-03-05 22:19:57.574012 |
|         42 |       4 |           5 | 2016-03-05 22:19:57.589436 |
|         43 |       4 |           5 | 2016-03-05 22:19:57.598959 |
|         44 |       4 |           5 | 2016-03-05 22:19:57.605516 |
```

I've tried things like:

```
"SELECT * FROM checkins WHERE user_id = " + req.body.userID + " AND TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, entered_at, current_timestamp(6)) < 5;"
```

AND

```
"SELECT * FROM checkins WHERE user_id = " + req.body.userID + " AND entered_at <= now() AND entered_at >= date_sub(now(),  interval 1 SECOND);"
```

None of which worked unfortunately. Thank you in advance for any guidance.

**EDIT**

For clarity, what I'm doing is trying to see if a particular user has made an entry within the last 5 seconds, down to the fractional second. If he has, then `rows.length > 0` will be true when rows returns on the server side. If in fact `rows.length` IS greater than zero, I set my `proceedToUpdateUsersLocation` variable to `false`. I hope that's a clear explanation. I'm trying to prevent multiple entries by checking that there were no duplicates in the table from within the past X seconds.

Comment: Because I want all of the duplicate entries from the table, so I use select

Comment: Ok - but first you talked about preventing duplicates. A select isn't going to cause duplicates

Comment: Oh I see what you're missing. If I return rows.length > 0 on the server it means that I have duplicates, so I set a variable to false so it will not update the users location again. This logic is being done server side. Here I'm just seeing if there was a previous entry, and I check that by seeing what the connection.query returns. Does that make sense?

Comment: Not really. What if 'the previous entry' occurs *while* you're checking?

Comment: That's why I check if the table has any entries from that particular user from within the last 5 seconds, it's just not catching the ones that happen within the same second. That's why in my code example they were all entered at the 57th second

Comment: Checking first is unnecessary and counter-productive. I'll post an example...

Comment: Please do, and thank you. I hope I made some sense. If not, I posted an edit trying to explain the situation as clearly as possible.

Comment: This one looks relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/913841/mysql-conditional-insert

Answer (score 0):

The solution was quite simple really, I just don't have the SQL skills necessary. What I did was subtract 4.999999 `SECONDS_MICROSECONDS` from `curtime(6)` using the `DATE_SUB()` function. Here's my final solution.

```
"SELECT * FROM checkins WHERE user_id = " + req.body.userID + " AND DATE_SUB(curtime(6), INTERVAL 4.999999 SECOND_MICROSECOND) < entered_at;"
```

Thank you all for your assistance, and I hope this will prove useful to someone.

Answer (score -1):

I think that pretty much any soluiton that does the check outside of the same transaction that inserts the data is bound to fail due to a race condition (unless you implement some locking, which may be a bad idea, it depends).

So, one way to solve it is to make sure that the database itself prevents duplicates.

I propose to pick a canonical value that would represent all the timestamps that you would like to merge, let's call it `canonical_timestamp` and create a unique constraint `UNIQUE (user_id, canonical_timestamp)`.

You can calculate `canonical_timestamp` before inserting your data as e.g. `int(time()/5)` or `5*int(time()/5)` or in any other way that fits your purpose of deduplicating the records.

**UPDATE**

Strictly speaking, this solution doesn't completely solve the problem when we receive two events close to the border:

```
ts = 5 -> canonical_ts = 1
ts = 6 -> canonical_ts = 2
```

Comment: Interesting. I will look into this and let you know asap! Thank you!