# MySQL - checking max rows during insert

Tags: mysql

We have a table where we limit the number of rows per user to a certain number. Before insert, we check if user has exceeded the storage capacity (number of rows) and then insert as appropriate. For example,

```
select count(id) from items where user=123;
```

say, if count < 10,

```
insert into items set user=123, a=xyx;
```

However, this approach requires two queries. Is there a way in which is can be done in a single query.

Thanks

Comment: You can use an insert trigger to check that and automaitcally cancel the insert if necessary. But that are in reality also 2 queries

Comment: instead u can use a procedure

Answer (score 0):

Pretty much any approach you take will require two queries.  Whether you do this in a trigger or in application code is a matter of choice.

If you use your method, then add an index on `items(user)`.  This will make it cheap to count the number of rows.

An alternative is to increment a value in the user table for each item.  So, when a user inserts an item, then increment `users.itemcount`.  Remember, though, to reduce the count when you delete items.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to have 1 query in a code you can try to use conditional insert with approach described here [MySQL Conditional Insert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/913841/mysql-conditional-insert)