# maria db insert or update

Tags: sql, mariadb

I have the following sql code:

```
UPDATE google_calendar_accounts SET google_refresh_token="d",google_org_token="d" WHERE userID=5;
IF ROW_COUNT()=0 THEN
INSERT INTO google_calendar_accounts (userID,google_refresh_token,google_org_token) VALUES (5,"d","d"); END IF
```

and I am getting the error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 2

I am using mariadb 10.1.14

Comment: If this is just in a normal query, that isn't going to work, conditionals and other constructs aren't supported outside of stored procedures.  You may want to examine this related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/913841/mysql-conditional-insert

Comment: Or from the official docs, another upsert approach: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/insert-on-duplicate-key-update/

Answer (score 4):

In spite the comment suggesting to do `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ...`, There may be a reason to do the update first, and insert just if there was no row affected, like the OP tried: this way auto increment won't be increased in vain.

So, a possible solution to the question may be using insert from select with a condition `where row_count()=0`

For example:

```
--first query
UPDATE google_calendar_accounts 
SET google_refresh_token='d',google_org_token='d' 
WHERE userID=5;
--second query use the affected rows of the previous query
INSERT IGNORE INTO google_calendar_accounts (userID,google_refresh_token,google_org_token)
SELECT 5,'d','d' WHERE ROW_COUNT()=0
```

BTW: I've added `IGNORE` to the insert query for a case there was a row match to the update condition but it wasn't updated since all columns was identical to the updated, like in the case before the update there was already row `5,'d','d'`. 
In such case, if the 5 is primary or unique key the query won't fail.

Comment: `INSERT IGNORE` might silently fail for other reasons than a duplicate key