# MySql inserting value or increment a field

Tags: mysql, conditional-statements, sql-insert

I have a table with these columns: `Player_name | Item_name | Amount`

I do not know how to perform this conditional `INSERT`:

```
INSERT INTO Needed_items(Player_name,Item_name) VALUES('foo','foo');
```

if `Player_name` and `Item_name` already exist, so if a Player already owns a given item, I need to increment `Amount` field, else I need to insert a new row into the table.
Thanks for the help

Comment: send your whole code.

Comment: That's my whole code, I have no idea how to write those conditions in mySQL language

Comment: Have you checked http://stackoverflow.com/questions/913841/mysql-conditional-insert?

Comment: @Guriandoro yes, but it didn't help me, I don't have unique columns in my table

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
INSERT INTO Needed_items(Player_name,Item_name) VALUES('foo','foo')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Amount=Amount+1
```

Comment: It doesn't work for me. It just adds another row to the table without incrementing anything

Comment: So you don't have unique items in the table. Can you give your create table syntax?