# insert visits after 5 minutes only

Tags: mysql, sql

I'd like to insert visits like this:

```
id - user - visit - data
1 - 1 - 2 - date
2 - 1 - 3 - date
3 - 1 - 2 - date after 5 minutes from the first (id 1) - only insert if it has pasted more than 5 minutes from the last similar record.
```

user 1 visited user 2 and 3.
The problem is, I'd like to insert visits without repeating them in the first 5 minutes. After this I'd like to insert.

I tried:

```
INSERT INTO visits (user, visit, data) 
SELECT '1', '2', NOW() WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM visits WHERE user = '1' AND visit = '2' AND data >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 5 MINUTE))
```

but it is not working. any ideas?

Comment: This seems correct [as seen here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/913841/mysql-conditional-insert) , can you make a sqlfiddle to reproduce the problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL Conditional Insert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/913841/mysql-conditional-insert)

Comment: You likely need a trigger for this.

Comment: @GordonLinoff can you give me some example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can express the logic in the `insert`:

```
INSERT INTO visits (user, visit, data) 
    SELECT u.user, u.visit, u.data
    FROM (SELECT 1 as user, 2 as visit, NOW() as data) u
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                      FROM visits v
                      WHERE v.user = u.user AND v.visit = u.visit AND
                            u.data >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 5 MINUTE)
                     );
```

This solves the problem for the particular `INSERT`.  And that might be good enough.  However, you are relying on the application to ensure data integrity.  A trigger would ensure that no inserts or updates take place that violate your rule.