# MYSQL - Multiple value insert into table where not exists in another

Tags: mysql, insert

I have PHP array(array has multiple values) and i want to add that data in table but before insert into table check for value is exist in another table, if value get in another table skip that value.

**Example:**

```
INSERT INTO table1('column1','column2','column3') VALUES
  ('val11','val11','val11'),
  ('val12','val12','val12')
    WHERE NOT EXIST 
      (SELECT * FROM table2 WHERE table2.column1 = VALUES(column1) AND 
        table2.column2 = VALUES(column2) AND table2.column3 = VALUES(column3)
```

Am I on the right path or is there a better way of doing this?

Thanks

Miten

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL Conditional Insert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/913841/mysql-conditional-insert)

Comment: I have multiple recordes @Nick

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [`INSERT ... SELECT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-select.html) syntax to achieve this result. Because you have multiple rows you have to `UNION` the data rows into one derived table, and then check that the values in that table don't exist in `table2`:

```
INSERT INTO table1 (column1, column2, column3)
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT 'val11' AS column1, 'val12' AS column2, 'val13' AS column3
      UNION
      SELECT 'val21', 'val22', 'val23') v
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * 
                  FROM table2 t2
                  WHERE t2.column1 = v.column1
                    AND t2.column2 = v.column2
                    AND t2.column3 = v.column3)
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=f8b3c7c286665f194a4b78600db3ae08)