# mysql use IF NOT NULL as part of transaction

Tags: mysql

I am using a MySQL transaction. If the initial  `where` `myHistoryNum` result (match name+rowActive) is not NULL, then continue the transaction.

I have tried various combinations, however cannot get the `insert` statement to trigger when `myHistoryNum` is set.

```
history | uuid | name  | rowActive
24      | abcd | Art   | 1          <<< is match, trigger an insert
999     | zxcv | Art   | 0          <<< no match, do not trigger insert
```

```
start transaction; 
select @myHistNum := max(history), @olduuid := uuid 
from mytable WHERE (name=art AND rowActive=1);

# START IS NOT NULL test
CASE WHEN @myHistNum IS NOT NULL THEN
set @histNum = @histNum  + 1;
INSERT INTO mytable 
.....
END;                                      <<<ALT, tried END AS;
commit;
```

also tried

```
IF @myHistNum IS NOT NULL
 THEN 
   .....
END IF;
commit;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL Conditional Insert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/913841/mysql-conditional-insert)

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken, control flow statements (like IF, WHEN) [can only be used within stored programs in MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/flow-control-statements.html)