# MySQL Use POINT coordinate as primary/unique key

Tags: mysql, geometry, spatial, database-indexes

I have a table with some data. I use type `POINT` because sometimes I need to select the data based on this parameter.

I need to add a constraint that will disallow the insert of the same pair of values.

I receive this error when I try to simply add a unique index.

```
Error 3728: Spatial indexes can't be primary or unique indexes
```

**Point can have negative values**. Thus, probably cantor pairing function is not the case for it to be stored as LONG/INT.

Is there any other way to implement that check?
I know I can use varchar for that but I'd like to use some data type like integer/decimal for that. Or maybe some kind of trigger that checks coming value is unique?

Either way, I want database-level control for that.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by using conditional insert:
[MySQL Conditional Insert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/913841/mysql-conditional-insert)

```
insert into `tbl` (`position`) select * from (select point(%f, %f) `p`) `tmp` where not exists ( select * from `tbl` `t` where `t`.`position` = `tmp`.`p` )
```

Please let me know if someone knows any other way.